# Finding a point on a polynomial function where there are 3 points where the line y=mx +c is touched

Tags: calculus, polynomials

$f(x)=x^6 +4x^5 -6x^4-32x^3+ax^2$

$y=m\cdot x+c$

where $m$ is the gradient and $c$ is the $y$-intercept

The question is that the function $f(x)$ has three $x$ values where it touches the tangent line given by $y=m\cdot x +c$

What would be a in order for this to happen?

And what is the tangent line's equation?

Comment: Use \cdot to emphasize multiplication.

Comment: yeah ok, I will next time

Comment: @P.Andrews: I think that this does not happen. In other words, there is no such tangent line. (if you need a proof about this, I'll show it.)

Comment: Sorry,I talked to my teacher about this and he had given the wrong equation, it is a in front of x^2 not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract $mx+c$ from the polynomial, and the result touches the $x$-axis at three points.  So 
$$(x-p)^2(x-q)^2(x-r)^2=x^6+4x^5-6x^4-32x^3+ax^2-mx-c$$
The 4,-6,-32 give three equations in $p,q,r$; then $p,q,r$ give $a,m,c$

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this is a unique problem. So let us see..

The line $y = m x + c$ is a tangent line to $f$, so it intersects $f$ at $x_0$ and shares the slope at $x_0$:
$$
y(x_0) = m x_0 + c = f(x_0) \\
m = f'(x_0)
$$
When I set this up in GeoGebra and vary the tangential location $x_0$, I get values with one, three or five intersections of the tangent line with the graph of $f$. So it seems not to be a unique problem.

The equation of the tangent line at $x_0$ is
$$
t(x) = f'(x_0) x + (f(x_0) - f'(x_0) x_0) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x - x_0)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I talked to my teacher and he had given the wrong equation, he had given an equation where he subbed 4 in for a. Check my updated question. I'm really sorry for wasting your time, I wasted a good hour on this too.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it resolved.